# What's the difference between a Fermat pseudoprime and a Carmichael number?

Tags: primality-test, pseudoprimes

I've read a lot of definitions in different places on the Internet and I'm confused since all of them express the same thing, but using seemingly different explanations.

Can somebody please point out the difference in a clear way?

Comment: A composite number $A$ is a Carmichael number if for all $a$ coprime with A one has             
   $a^{A-1}\equiv 1\pmod A$. The composite $B$ is Fermat pseudoprime when a  number $b$ is such that $b^{B-1}\equiv 1\pmod B$. Try to see clearly that all Carmichael number is Fermat pseudoprime but not the reciproque.

Comment: @Piquito Are there more restrictions for $a$, $b$? Some of the sources I consulted mentioned $A-1$, and $B-1$ as upper bounds for possible values of $a$ and $b$ respectively, while others omitted this restriction.

Comment: $341$ is a Fermat pseudoprime to base $2$, but is not a Carmichael number.

Comment: (1) I think the upper bound is not necessary because the context is modular arithmetic so, for example modulo $7$ you identify $4$ with all number of the form $4+7n$. Both notions, Carmichael and pseudoprime, have as "model" Fermat Little Theorem. Do you have examples of NOT PRIME numbers which satisfy this theorem however while a pseudoprime "imitates" to Fermat with a number $b$ as "base", this number

Comment: (2) can be just one single while in Carmichael case the thing goes for ALL coprimes with $A$. Pseudoprime "mimics" FLT with a single (maybe more)  number but Carmichael completely satisfies the theorem without being a prime (in short, $p$ prime implies FLT but not the reciprocal).

Comment: @Piquito Now it all makes sense! Thanks a lot for the explanation. PS: Please answer the question "officially" so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Ok, because you asked me that with a "please" (I guess it is useful for you) but let me improve something what I have said.

Comment: This is sort of like the difference between bulldogs and French bulldogs. All French bulldogs are bulldogs, but not all bulldogs are French bulldogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In elementary theory of numbers there are two very important theorems in relation to prime numbers, Fermat's little theorem and Wilson's theorem. But while the first one does not characterize the prime numbers the second one does because $ p $ is prime if and only if $p$ satisfies Wilson's theorem.

The above implies that there are composite numbers that satisfy, totally or partially, Fermat's little theorem. These are the Fermat pseudoprimes  and the  Carmichael numbers.

A composite number $A$ is a **Carmichael number** if for all $a$ coprime with $A$ one has $a^{A−1}≡1\pmod A$. The composite $B$ is a **Fermat pseudoprime** when some number $b$ is such that $b^{B−1}≡1\pmod B$.

Fermat pseudoprimes "mimics" FLT with a single (maybe more) number but Carmichael completely satisfies the theorem without being a prime.

In short, $p$ prime implies $FLT$ but not the reciprocal while $p$ prime is equivalent to satisfy Wilson's theorem.

Example (1).- The composite number $91$ is Fermat pseudoprime because $3^{90}\equiv 1\pmod {91}$.

Example (2).- The composite number $561$ is Carmichael because for all $a$ coprime with $561$ one has the same property $a^{560}\equiv 1\pmod{561}$ as for FLT.